# How can we cut the bar chart based on a criteria

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I have generated the following plot. I want to cut the bar chart with a line when the IV value is above 0.0015 and display that line.

```
ggplot(data = WOE_categorical_summary, aes(x = reorder(Variable, -IV), y = IV)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "orange") + 
  geom_text(aes(label=IV)) + 
  labs(xlab = "Variables") +
  bar_theme1
```

[image]

Comment: try: `y = ifelse(IV >  0.0015,  0.0015, IV)` and geom line with `y = ifelse(IV >  0.0015,  0.0015, NA)`

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. It helped!

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is to just add an additional layer to your code:

```
+ geom_hline(aes( yintercept = 0.0015))
```